# MariaDB service fails immediately after installation - CentOS7

Tags: centos, mariadb

MariaDB service could not start after installation, fresh CentOS7 install with no Apache or PHP yet. Though it has Webmin panel installed but nothing other than that.

The error message that I am getting is as following:

> Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with
>   error code. See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl
>   -xe" for details.

Comment: see the actual error by typing systemctl status mariadb.service or journal -xe in the command line as suggested first - right after receiving the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw the actual error, did not made sense to me. Went on serverfault and many other websites but no luck. After that tried installing MariaDB with root user with "sudo" prefix and it did the trick.

By the way I was following process from following URL: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/yum/

Answer (score 6):

I was trying to restore my database and faced similar issue which was solved by removing log files:
`/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0 /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1`

May be you should try by:

```
mv /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0 ~/
mv /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1 ~/
service mysql start
```

If works delete log files:

```
rm ~/ib_logfile0 ~/ib_logfile1
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution could be to run the given series of commands after installation of MariaDB,

```
  mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/

  mysql_secure_installation

  systemctl start mariadb
```

Comment: when input password and press enter, It shows me `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)` error.

Answer (score 2):

My issue was a permission problem -

I found this in `/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log`

> [ERROR] mysqld: Can't create/write to file
>   '/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid' (Errcode: 13)
>
> [ERROR] Can't start
>   server: can't create PID file: Permission denied

So I changed the owner of `/var/run/mariadb` from `root` to `mysql`

Started up fine after that.

Comment: makes sense, I can relate it to my solution - different way though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using InnoDB, you have another chance before wiping all your data or reinstalling the whole thing.

You could just try to force a recovery by simply adding: `innodb_force_recovery = 1` to your `/etc/my.cnf`.

Once the service starts again, you can fix the corrupted data and set `innodb_force_recovery` back to 0 or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I had /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.index file's owner as root. Changed the owner and group to mysql and it worked. Don't know how it got changed though. The problem started after updating the packages and doing a system restart.